# node.js express nested callback in route

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

getting error "could not locate bindings file"

trying to search for blog posting, then lookup banner based on blog abbrev, then write out

without banner lookup, everything works fine

think we are screwing up the callback but can't find good example

```
app.get("/posting/:id", function(req,res) {
  var db = app.get('db');
  var id = [req.params.id];
  console.log(id);
  db.run("select * from postings where id=$1",[1], function(err,posting) {
    console.log(posting);
    var choice = posting[0].choice;
    var banner = banner_lookup(choice, function(err, banner) {
      console.log(banner); 
      res.render("posting", {posting:posting[0], banner:banner});       
    });
  }); 
});
function banner_lookup(abbrev) {
  console.log("banner lookup");
  for (i=0;i++;i<banners.length) {
    if (abbrev == banners[i].abbrev) {
      console.log(banners[i]);
      return (banners[i]);
    }
  }
  return {"name":"","color":"#000"};
}
var banners = [{"abbrev":"aaa","name":"Newsletter A", "color":"#888888"}];
```

Comment: Are you familiar with SQL injection attacks?

Comment: What do you mean *getting error "could not locate bindings file"*? That's not a JIT error and its not in your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies in this part of the program. You are basically passing two arguments to the `banner_lookup` function - the variable `choice` and the callback function where you expect the banner to be available after the lookup

```
var banner = banner_lookup(choice, function(err, banner) {
  console.log(banner); 
  res.render("posting", {posting:posting[0], banner:banner});       
});
```

However the actual function definition of `banner_lookup` accepts only one named argument - the `choice`. The `banner_lookup` function calculates and returns the banner value but it is not being passed to the callback function like you expect it to. You will have to explicitly write the functionality to support callback functionality in `banner_lookup`

Your code (with callback functionality) would look like this

```
function banner_lookup(abbrev, callback) {
   console.log("banner lookup");
   var bannerOutput = {"name":"","color":"#000"};
   for (i=0;i++;i<banners.length) {
      if (abbrev == banners[i].abbrev) {
          console.log(banners[i]);
          bannerOutput = banners[i];
      }
   }
   if(typeof callback == "function") {
       callback(null, bannerOutput);
   } else {
       return bannerOutput;
   }
 }
```

The above method now accepts a `callback` parameter, and if it is defined as a function, then passes the output to the function else returns it like earlier.

**Tip 1** : You don't really need to implement callback functionality if the `banner_lookup` function is doing simple tasks in sync. You can simply write

```
   var banner = banner_lookup(choice);
   console.log(banner);
```

This banner will have the expected result.

**Tip 2** : And as Amit pointed out in his comment, read about SQL injection attacks. Make sure you sanitize all variables that go into making a DB query (You are directly accepting the `id` parameter from the route and passing it to the DB query which can be easily misused.

Comment: okay, thks for the callback help - that should work.  w/o a callback the view response was firing before the banner lookup  thks for caution on injection - implementing jwt is next on task list.    Sorry about binding error - a db module got dropped when we were trying various things to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

Your function banner_lookup requires only 1 parameter on its decleration, yet you pass it 2 when you call it (choise and the callback function).